# How can I remove the "Add New" button in my custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, filters, wp-admin

I have many custom post types that need the Add [custom post type] feature but I have a custom post type of "About" and I do not need to "Add New" about to the about custom post type. So I want to remove the button on top that says "Add About"

This is what I mean:

[image]

Any idea how I can remove that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please refer below :

```
function disable_new_posts() {
    // Hide sidebar link
    global $submenu;
    unset($submenu['edit.php?post_type=CUSTOM_POST_TYPE'][10]);

    // Hide link on listing page
    if (isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] == 'CUSTOM_POST_TYPE') {
        echo '<style type="text/css">
        #favorite-actions, .add-new-h2, .tablenav { display:none; }
        </style>';
    }
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'disable_new_posts');
```

Comment: Thank really appreciate it, just one other question about the code. Can it be used to remove other elemnts on that same page? like for example the "Search About" to the rite.

Comment: Yes, but for that you need to change necessary elements in code.

Comment: This no longer works as it will give a "headers already sent" error message.

Answer (score 52):

A prettier solution would be to disable the capability of creating a custom_post_type:

Simply pass the the parameter `'create_posts' => 'do_not_allow',` in the capabilities array when calling `register_post_type`.

```
$args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'Custom Post Type', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Custom Post Type', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'map_meta_cap'        => true,
        'capabilities' => array(
            'create_posts' => 'do_not_allow'
        )
    );
    register_post_type( 'custom_post_type', $args );
```

Comment: Is there a drawback to doing it this way? This seems like a much better solution than just hiding the links with CSS.

Comment: Confirming that this works! It should be the accepted answer because it doesn't rely on CSS hacks.

Comment: Doesn't appear to work on `4.7.2` ... Besides. It's not even supposed to accept a `boolean` value. It should be a `string` value of: `do_not_allow`.

Comment: not a preferred solution, sometime you should not be able to just create "posts" without a pre determined context. Somethings are just UX candy and the alternative of trying to give capabilities based on context in the admin is  non maintainable nightmare.

Comment: There's a related WP bug #22895 (https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22895) which causes the edit.php page for the CPT to not be shown if there would be only "All posts" menu item in the CPT admin submenu. There's a workaround for it at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/178033/disable-posts-only-allow-to-edit-existing-pages-not-create-new-ones-create-po.

Comment: To be able to select role-by-role who can create CPT posts you should have 'capabilities' => array('create_posts' => 'create_custom_post_types')) where 'custom_post_types' is the name of your CPT with 's' added. Or the second item in capability_type array if you defined it that way.

Comment: this works in 4.9.4 replacing 'create_posts' => false with 'create_posts' => 'do_not_allow'. And 'capability_type' => 'custom_post_type' can be removed, is not necessary

Answer (score 4):

Then, if you just want to remove *Add New* and you are not using `custom_post_type`, you should't use `'capability_type' => 'custom_post_type'`. You'd better to remove this code. Good luck :)

So, the demo is below:

```
array(
'labels' => $member_labels,
'has_archive' => true,
'public' => true,
'hierarchical' => true, // like page
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'member_pages'),
'supports' => array(
    'title',
    'editor',
    'excerpt',
    'custom-fields',
    'thumbnail',
    'page-attributes',
),
'taxonomies' => array('post_tag', 'cm_club'),
// 'capability_type' => 'custom_post_type',
'capabilities' => array(
    'create_posts' => false,
),
'map_meta_cap' => true,
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Edited @TompaLompa's answer as it was incomplete. Adding `create_posts => false` won't work if `map_meta_cap` is not set to `true`.

Not setting this parameter (or setting it to `false`) will disable editing of the post type too. This is because you would need to add `edit_post` capability to each user role in order to **add** AND **edit** your post type.

Setting this parameter will use WP internal default meta capability handling and make it work for you if you don't need more finer control over role capabilities then the default WP ones.

Answer (score -1):

Best way i felt is install add-admin-javascript plugin and activate it
then go to settings and add javascript
write this code in last box

```
$('.wrap .wp-heading-inline').remove();
$('.wrap .page-title-action').remove();
$('#wp-admin-bar-new-content').remove();
```