# Disable 'Add New' in custom post that is made from CPT UI

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins

I have been trying to find a way to disable the Add New button in my custom post type that I have generated using CPT UI plugin. I have tried this solution - [How can I remove the "Add New" button in my custom post type?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/169170/how-can-i-remove-the-add-new-button-in-my-custom-post-type?newreg=150cafdd909a4720bb1ab0a79228413c)
but no luck.

I know there is a way to do it in register_post_type function, however, my post type was already created using the plugin and have some data saved already. If I use the function, I will have to create all the contents all over again.

Please help

Comment: Changing a post type setting isn't going to delete your content.

Comment: you could always just hide it with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [Milo](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/4771/milo). Didn't consider adding the register_post_type in my functions before because I thought it would interfere with the existing custom post type I made in CPT UI, turns out that it is useful and it override the CPT UI post type.

I used the same slug and it automatically connected the data to the manually created post type. Here's the code:

```
function create_post_type() {
register_post_type( 'office_post', array(
  'capability_type' => 'post',
  'capabilities' => array(
    'create_posts' => false, // Removes support for the "Add New" function ( use 'do_not_allow' instead of false for multisite set ups )
  ), 
  'labels' => array(
    'name' => __( 'Office' ),
    'singular_name' => __( 'Office' )
  ),
  'map_meta_cap' => true, // Set to `false`, if users are not allowed to edit/delete existing posts
  'public' => true,
  'menu_icon' => 'http://architecture.com/testdrive/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/logo-white-e1524992076968.png',
));
} 
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
```