# Hide add new page button

Tags: posts, pages, css

I want to hide the add new page button from users that are not administrators. I managed to hide the submenu item from the right column like this:

```
$page = remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=page', 'post-new.php?post_type=page' );
```

I tried to hide the button in the page with css proposed in this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/169170/how-can-i-remove-the-add-new-button-in-my-custom-post-type) but didn't work. How I can achieve that? Here is my -failed- attempt:

```
if (isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] == 'page') {
            echo '<style type="text/css">
            #favorite-actions, .add-new-h2, .tablenav { display:none; }
            </style>';
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove the "Add New" button in my custom post type?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/169170/how-can-i-remove-the-add-new-button-in-my-custom-post-type)

Comment: @MaxYudin that solution didn't work in my code

Comment: There are three solutions.

Comment: @MaxYudin none of them are suitable for my problem. I don't want to disable the capabilities because I want to hide it only for specific users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved easy enough with just CSS.  First we are going to add a function that will output a class to the body tag based on what role the user is.  Then we will enqueue a stylesheet to show up in the admin.  Then use the class in the body to target and hide the button.

**Add Body Class Based on User Role** - Add to functions.php

```
function custom_role_admin_body_class( $classes ) {
    global $current_user;
    foreach( $current_user->roles as $role )
        $classes .= ' role-' . $role;
    return trim( $classes );
}
add_filter( 'admin_body_class', 'custom_role_admin_body_class' );
```

**Enqueue Admin Styles** - Add to functions.php

```
function custom_admin_styles(){
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'admin_css', 
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/admin-styles.css', array(), filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/css/admin-styles.css') 
    );
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_admin_styles');
```

**Use Body Class to Hide Button for NON admin users**

```
body.edit-php.post-type-page:not(.role-administrator) .page-title-action {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I added these lines in functions.php and created a new file css/admin-styles.css for the third code snippet but didn't work

Comment: Can you tell me where exact I create the admin-style.css? Probably I ve put in in wrong directory thats why is not working.... I've tested it under wp-content/themes/my_theme/css/ and under wp-admin/css/

Comment: hmmm no its not there... doesn't show up in source

Comment: if you inspect the page (f12) are you getting a 404 error?  find the stylesheet in the inspector and clikc the link

Comment: ok thank you! it was a typo :( . Thank you very much for your effort and time. I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

install `User Role Editor` this plugin that will give you the option to hide options by user roles and let me know this works or not so i can give another option to do it.

Comment: I would like to do it without using a plugin. is that possible?